# Device not accerpting APKs from other android device. (through Bluetooth)

Tags: file-transfer

I am  trying to transfer APKS from my Moto G to Android one through Buetooth (I have unknown sources enabled) but it is not being transferred. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download ES File Explorer and change the file's extension to txt, like this:

[image]

So when the other device gets the file, you remove the ".txt" and it'll be an APK again.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way around this is to download apk share ! 
You can create apk's for your apps and share them through different means ! 
Link to app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kayan.nurav.apkshare&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dapk+share&pcampaignid=APPU_8xc6VIiBA8e0uQSTiYJo